# Shorthand way to fill all columns and rows with borders in a grid?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm creating a 15x15 grid with borders around each cell (without any overlapping) in XAML for a WPF project. I would go about this by doing something like this:

```
<Grid Width="675" Height="675" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,10">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="45"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="45"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="45"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="45"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="45"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="45"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="45"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="45"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="45"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="45"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="45"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="45"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="45"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="45"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="45"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="45"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="45"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="45"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="45"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="45"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="45"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="45"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="45"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="45"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="45"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="45"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="45"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="45"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="45"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="45"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="15" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2"/>
    <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="15" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2,0,2,2"/>
    <Border Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="15" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2,0,2,2"/>
    <Border Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="15" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2,0,2,2"/>
    <Border Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="15" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2,0,2,2"/>
    <Border Grid.Row="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="15" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2,0,2,2"/>
    <Border Grid.Row="6" Grid.ColumnSpan="15" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2,0,2,2"/>
    <Border Grid.Row="7" Grid.ColumnSpan="15" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2,0,2,2"/>
    <Border Grid.Row="8" Grid.ColumnSpan="15" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2,0,2,2"/>
    <Border Grid.Row="9" Grid.ColumnSpan="15" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2,0,2,2"/>
    <Border Grid.Row="10" Grid.ColumnSpan="15" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2,0,2,2"/>
    <Border Grid.Row="11" Grid.ColumnSpan="15" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2,0,2,2"/>
    <Border Grid.Row="12" Grid.ColumnSpan="15" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2,0,2,2"/>
    <Border Grid.Row="13" Grid.ColumnSpan="15" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2,0,2,2"/>
    <Border Grid.Row="14" Grid.ColumnSpan="15" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2,0,2,2"/>

    <Border Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="15" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2"/>
    <Border Grid.Column="3" Grid.RowSpan="15" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2"/>
    <Border Grid.Column="5" Grid.RowSpan="15" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2"/>
    <Border Grid.Column="7" Grid.RowSpan="15" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2"/>
    <Border Grid.Column="9" Grid.RowSpan="15" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2"/>
    <Border Grid.Column="11" Grid.RowSpan="15" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2"/>
    <Border Grid.Column="13" Grid.RowSpan="15" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2"/>
</Grid>
```

[Result grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFKGL.png)

I'm trying to cut down on code length. Is there any way I can write this same grid in a shorter way? Maybe a property that automatically fills the borders of all columns/rows? If I surround my grid in a border it can cover the outsides; maybe there's a way to have it fill in each cell's borders?

Any ideas guys? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why do you have such a Grid at all? Why not an ItemsControl with a UniformGrid as ItemsPanel and the Border in its ItemTemplate?

Answer (score -1):

If you want a border of specifically 2 units between all grid cells, you could apply a uniform 1-unit border for each `<Border>` tag and then a uniform 1-unit border around the grid itself to complete the "outside" border. If you wanted a border of an uneven number (1, 3, 5, and so on) this would become more difficult, but I think Clemen's idea of using a UniformGrid is a more robust solution.